# How to avoid exposing secret when using Plaid from client app

Tags: plaid

I'm adding a Plaid client to my java desktop software. The problem is I don't see any way to have it talk directly to the Plaid server without needing to embed the *secret* within the app. Is there a way for my app to talk directly to Plaid without needing to know and send the secret string for every request?

A primary goal is to avoid ever having customer financial data on my server, even if it is only in transit.

My server could handle the link token creation, and maybe access token exchange, and then provide those tokens to the client app. My hope was that the client_id and access_token would be enough for the app to perform subsequent exchanges directly with Plaid's server, but alas the `secret` is required for every message.

An alternate solution would be if all request bodies could be public-key encrypted and then proxied through my server which verified the client and added the secret as an http header. I haven't found any reference to this ability in the current or upcoming/beta API.

This must have been done before, so any hints as to how to handle this scenario is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

The solution you're describing sounds like it would work -- it doesn't seem like specific capabilities to support this need to be built into the API to make it work, unless I'm missing something?

Depending on your use case, you might also consider what financial data you are avoiding having on your server and why and simply not requesting that data. For example, Auth endpoints can be used with Plaid partners via a processor token, which allows you to avoid ever touching actual account and routing number data.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response Alex.  I'm still new to Plaid, but in order to make this work I'd need for the Plaid http API to not require the `secret` field in every request. Either that, or allow the JSON request and response bodies to be public-key encrypted between the app and the Plaid server. The first one would be the ideal situation.

Comment: As for the financial data we'd like to avoid having on our server, that would be any customer financial data: accounts and transactions. We'd like for all communication to be done between the runs-on-customer-devices apps and the Plaid server (as well as OAUTH with banks, of course). We view having any customer data in our own possession as a potential liability.

Comment: Not sure why the request bodies need to be encrypted for this to work? Seems like you could just send the information needed to put together the request body from the client to your server over https and then construct the request (including adding the secret) there. It would be helpful to know which endpoints you're using, but in general, the information used for a Plaid request body doesn't typically contain financial information or PII.

Comment: Hi Alex, if we're using the transactions and investments endpoints the responses would include financial info, which would at least briefly pass through our server. Unless I'm missing something, which is very possible!

Comment: Got it -- your original question suggested encrypting the request, but not the response, hence my confusion. The responses from the API are sent over https and are encrypted in transit. Most Plaid clients' use cases involve apps that support web access and so not wanting to have any financial data on a server is not a typical use case. You can certainly send the data on to the client and never store it on the server, but I personally am not sure of a way to never have the data touch your server in transit.